# "-[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance" when trying to access objectArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am trying to load next 10 rows of data in tableView when program fetches the last row in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I am using single function with pagenumber parameter to load the consecutive pages.
It works for first fetch i.e. pagenumber 0, but when I call it again to fetch next page rows, it gives me this error

```
-[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

After banging my head for a long time, I've found that it creates this problem when trying to access the NSMutableArray of my Model objects. 
I am using it this way :

```
TableRowObjectClass* TempObject = [[TableRowObject alloc] init];
for(int i=0;i<rowArray.count;i++){
    TempObject = [rowArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString* objectProperty = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"String Property I need from Object to be appended with some text from TableRowObject Class : %@",TempObject.objProperty] retain];
    [propertyArray addObject:objectProperty];
    [objectProperty release];
}
```

Here I get array of Model Objects(TableRowObjectClass's Objects) and I want to extract objectProperty from TempObject and create and array of all those properties.
Initially, for `pagenumber` 0, it fetches 20 rows, now when I am displaying 20th row I call fetch, which call this function to create a fresh Array of `objectProperty` and I call `[TableView reloadData]` to show the frsh feed with 20(old)+20(fresh) feeds.

Now its creating this error

```
-[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

when trying to access,

```
NSString* objectProperty = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"String Property ....TableRowObject Class: %@",TempObject.objProperty] retain];
```

I am not sure what and where is it getting `dealloc`. 
I've spent alot of hours on this and I am not really good with objective-c memory management.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is TableRowObject a class or a variable? You appear to be using it both ways.

Comment: Its a class with its own init method. Objects for it are being created by parsing JSON data and are returned in a NSMutable array of those objects.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed it in the post above. This is not the actual code. (can't paste the exact code, company policy) I am trying to show the functionality, which is similar to code presented above now.

Answer (score 5):

Your code pretty clearly indicates that you don't understand Objective-C or Objective-C memory management;   no worries, we've all started there.   Start by reading the [Objective-C guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html), then the [Memory Management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Some specific issues:

```
TableRowObjectClass* TempObject = [[TableRowObject alloc] init];
TempObject = [someArray objectAtIndex: 0];
```

That leaks. the object allocated on the first line (the variable should start with a lower case letter, too).

This:

```
NSString* objectProperty = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"..."] retain];
[objectProperty release];
```

A double retain balanced by a single release, another leak.

That you are seeing `message sent to deallocated instance` errors indicates that you are over-releaseing other objects.  Follow the memory management guidelines, use "build and analyze", and then use the Zombie detection tool....

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I came across another problem, I am using a class method and returning a dictionary. But when I try to initialize it as autorelease the app crashes as it is being used in another class method

Comment: That an object is being returned from a class method or instance method makes *absolutely no difference* as far as memory management is concerned....

Answer (score 1):

There is no necessity to use

```
NSString* objectProperty = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"String Property ....TableRowObject : %@",TableRowObject.objProperty] retain];
```

you can even use

```
NSString* objectProperty = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"String Property ....TableRowObject : %@",TableRowObject.objProperty];
```

Comment: I was initially using that 

(NSString* objectProperty = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"String Property ....TableRowObject : %@",TableRowObject.objProperty];)

 only, but in desperation to solve this bug, and not autorelease any object, I used that 

(NSString* objectProperty = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"String Property ....TableRowObject : %@",TableRowObject.objProperty] retain];)
.

Comment: what kind of objects you have in TableRowObject

Comment: I am defining this class myself, its a regular class inherited from NSObject.